# how to delete main category and subcategories

Tags: php, mysql

i could not figure it out how to delete subs sub categories when i delete main category.

I made two queries. This works when i delete sub and sub sub. But if the category i am deleting is the main cat. i can not delete the subs sub.

What should i do here to delete the car, fiat and panda if the id is 1?

```
cats_id cats_parentid cats_name 
1           0           car
2           1          fiat 
3           2          panda

mysql_query("DELETE FROM cats 
            WHERE cats_id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_query("DELETE FROM cats 
            WHERE cats_parentid='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: If you tables are InnoDB, you could make a relation that handles this automatically when you remove the parent row.

Comment: Just execute your second query first

Comment: yes, just execute second query first. swap last two lines

Comment: how will it work if i swap them? I want to delete cats_id 1,2,3 if the id is 1. even if i swap them i will still have cats_id 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive function calls like this (in PHP):

```
function delete_subcats($id) {
  $res = mysql_query('SELECT cats_id FROM cats WHERE cats_parentid = '.$id);

  if ($res) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
      delete_subcats($row['cats_id']);
  }

  mysql_query('DELETE FROM cats WHERE cats_id = '.$id);
}
```

Or if you use InnoDB engine for your tables you need to create foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE cats ADD FOREIGN KEY (cats_parentid) REFERENCES cats(cats_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

and after you delete parent record all the connected records will be deleted by MySQL database without other queries.

Comment: it did not delete all sub categories when i delete the main one. It just deleted the category which has got the same id. and i could not add foreign key i get this error ` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES(cats_id) ON DELETE CASCADE' at line 1 `

Comment: I`ve updated both function and ALTER TABLE, all works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may set up your `cats_parentid` as foreign key so that the records are deleted when they get orphaned. See the mysql docs for syntax and further info.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: The problem is that this works only with InnoDB and other *relational* engines.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a function that deletes all childrens first recursively, for example:

```
function delete_cat($id){
    // Try to delete all the childrens first
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT cats_id WHERE  cats_parentid='".$id."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
        delete_cat($row['cats_id']);
    }

    // Then delete the cat after all the childrens are deleted
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM cats WHERE cats_id='".$id."'");
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This will work, though if the tree is deep and with many children, I'd suggest to populate list of ID first and then delete them in one query. To minimize number of selects, populating should be done for *sets of parents* rather than for *single parents*, i.e., if parent with ID 1 has 2 children with ID 2 and 3, then determining children of items with 2 and 3 should be done as `select id from category where parent_id in (2, 3)`. Next query might be `... where parent_id in (4, 5, 6, 7)`, where items with ID "4" and "5" might be children of "2", items with ID "6" and "7" - children of "3".